# Compactification of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, algebraic-groups

Is there any singular compactification of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$? Only compactification is known to me is $\mathbb{P}^3$. Does anyone know any other compactification?

Comment: Neretin ([2003](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1995383); [pdf](http://www.esi.ac.at/static/esiprpr/esi971.pdf)) discusses compactifications by Semple and others — have you checked what they boil down to for $\mathrm{PGL}_2$?

Comment: In rank 1 they all boil down to the same thing.

Comment: What's the meaning of "singular compactification"?

Comment: @YCor notice that the question is about a smooth-but-not-projective variety which admits a compactification by a smooth variety, $\mathbb P^3$. A singular compactification would simply be a singular variety which also contains a copy of $PGL(2,\mathbb C)$ as a dense open subset (which forces any singular points to lie in the complement of this copy, lending credence to the use of the word "singular" to describe the compactification itself).

Comment: @YCor I simply meant the compact variety is not smooth..but i understand it could mean something else..that the complement of $PGL_2$ is not smooth itself etc...actually i am interested in Blow downs of $\mathbb{P}^3$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer depends on how much symmetry of $PGL(2)$ you want to retain.

If the compactification is to be equivariant for left and right multiplication then, indeed, $\mathbb P^3$ is the only normal compactification. This follows easily from the embedding theory of spherical varieties.

If no symmetry is to be preserved then simply blow up up $\mathbb P^3$ in some crazy curve in the boundary and you obtain with probabilty one a singular variety.

Interesting is the case where only left but not right multiplication extends to the compactification. Here, the group $SL(2)$ has been studied extensively but the results for $PGL(2)$ are pretty much the same (just devide by the center).

On of the first systematic investigation in theis direction is "Quasihomogeneous affine algebraic varieties of the group SL(2)" by V.L. Popov. He classifies normal *affine* $SL(2)$-varieties on which $SL(2)$ has an open orbit. If the isotropy group of the generic orbit is finite then pretty much none of these spaces is smooth.

A typical example is the orbit closure of a nullform $x^df(x,y)$ where $f$ is homogeneous of degree $<d$. Note that all of these spaces can be equivariantly compactified.

Later Luna-Vust classified *all* left equivariant embeddings of $SL(2)$. There are plenty. Lucy Moser determined all normal embeddings of $SL(2)/\Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ finite. In particular $PGL(2)$ is covered.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain other compactifications by blow ups.

Namely the boundary divisor is given by the determinant hypersurface $\mathrm{det}(x)=0$. This is stratified by matrices of lower rank, and these strata are invariant under the action of $PGL_2$. Therefore blowing-up one of the higher codimension strata gives a new compactification of $PGL_2$.

I think however that all compactifications obtained this way will be smooth, as the strata appear to be smooth.

Comment: don't mind me saying this is obvious.. i want something which is not obtained by blowing up $\mathbb{P}^3$...blowing down is allowed though...but i am not sure how to blow down $\mathbb{P}^3$ for this purpose

Comment: but from what you said ...in the matrices of lower ranks i.e, $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ there is a $PGL_2$ invariant subset which contains elements of the form [a:0:c:0]....this line i think can be blown down therefore to get a new compactification...this would be singular

Comment: In your question you explicitly say that "Only compactification is known to me is $\mathbb{P}^3$. Does anyone know any other compactification?" If this is blow-up construction is obvious to you, why didn't you say so in the question? As written, my answer answers your second question. If you want more helpful answers, you should make more clear what you know or want in your question.

Comment: I think what Daniel Loughran writes is correct.  Any compactification of PGL_2 is birational to P^3 and hence can be obtained by blowups and blowdowns.  If my memory serves, the centers can be taken to be smooth too.  In addition, if one view PGL_2 as a subset of P^3, there can be no complete subvarieties (i.e. a P^1 x P^1) .